# Menpofit dlib: UnsatisfiableError during installation on Windows 10 using conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, dlib, menpo

I have been trying to install menpofit on a clean installation of anaconda for a while now. I have followed the [instructions on the menpo project website for Windows](http://www.menpo.org/installation/windows/expert.html), but I get the following error when I try to install menpofit using `conda install -c menpo menpofit`.

Error Message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- menpofit -> dlib 18.16 -> boost 1.56.0 -> python 3.5*
- menpofit -> menpo 0.6.* -> matplotlib 1.4.* -> pyparsing 2.0.1
- python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What I have tried:

Running `conda install -c menpo menpo` did not produce an error. I attempted to install dlib and boost using `conda-forge`, but this did not change the error message. I tried creating the conda environment using python 3.5. This seemed to install, but I quickly ran into a host of new problems with modules not being found and plenty of other errors that deserve their own question threads. Rebooting the computer or reinstalling anaconda did not seem to change anything.

For reference, I am running python 3.6 on a 32bit Window 10 computer.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually settled on using python 2.7 (`conda create -n envname python=2.7`). This seems to have solved all of my dependency issues.